# TSP with a twist

Tags: heuristics, traveling-salesman, directed-graph

I've encountered a problem that is very similar to the Traveling Salesman Problem, except with a few twists:

1. You are able to visit the same node multiple times
2. Traveling an edge that you have already traversed before is costless
3. The graph is directed

Of course, this problem is NP-complete, since this is a variation of the TSP, but I was wondering if there are any algorithms that have been designed for the regular TSP that can be easily modified to fit this particular problem?

Comment: If traversing already-visited edges is costless then I don't believe this is TSP at all. I think finding a Minimum Spanning Tree would be the the basis of an optimal solution - and be done in O(m log n) time with Kruskal's algorithm.

Comment: @Dai That would be a great solution - but I neglected to mention that the graph is directed... So a Minimum Spanning Tree cannot be used as a solution. I've updated my question to show this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you are describing is the **graphical, asymmetric TSP**. To break down the constraints you described,

3 Is the asymmetric TSP (ATSP), i.e., the TSP on a directed graph. This is much harder than the TSP in general, but it is a pretty well-studied problem. Off the top of my head, the Lin-Kernighan-Helsgaun (LKH) heuristic is a TSP heuristic that also performs respectably on the ATSP, and I'm sure there are others.

1 Is the graphical TSP, i.e., the TSP where you can visit nodes multiple times. I would not exactly call this problem well-studied. There is a good body of work on it, but most of it is in the context of results that can be mined for the standard TSP.

Constraint 2 confused me quite a bit but I think it is a red herring, because it is already implied by the graphical TSP. Another way to think of the graphical TSP is that you want a connected subgraph of your original graph where every node has degree at least two, whereas in the TSP the degree is equal to two. Thus we only incur the cost of visiting the edge once.

So to tie this up with your question! If I had to go with an "easily modified" algorithm from TSP methods, I would:

-Compute a starting ATSP tour using LKH, because such a tour is feasible for your problem, so it provides an upper bound.

-Write a formulation of the graphical ATSP in a commercial integer programming solver such as CPLEX or Gurobi. I would use the Held-Karp relaxation for the ATSP with the degree equations changed to allow multiple visits to a given city.

-Write a callback to the IP solver for adding connectivity constraints, in the case that it returns a disconnected solution.

-Pass the LKH tour to the IP solver as a warm start/numerical upper bound.

And then hope for the best! Basically, this would be a watered down version of a cutting plane-based TSP solver adapted to fit your problem. I wouldn't count on it to solve large scale instances, but I think this would give a respectable attempt.